# How do I see what a JBoss deployment uses?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

In a JBoss environment (specifically EAP 6) with several JARs deployed, several data sources, a lot of system properties, etc. How can I find what a particular JAR users?

For example, is there anyway I can see that "deployment-1.jar" uses "datasource-1" "system-property-2" and "system-property-5"?

What about the reverse? Eg finding out which deployments use a particular datasource?

Note: I'm looking at this from the perspective of an App Admin, maintaining a production system without necessarily having access to the source code.

Comment: You might be able to see some information in CLI. Something like `/deployment=*:read-resource(recursive=true, include-runtime=true)`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins +1 Thanks, I hadn't actually thought to try that. It does provide *some* information that I was struggling to find, but not everything (it shows some of the JMS queue names and I can see some System Properties being referenced for example)